# The Users are so shy (Expanded user card z index issue in close dialog)

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close, user-card

I am about to vote to close a question as duplicate of another one here in MSE.

I opened the close dialog, clicked dupe and pasted the link in it. While scrolling down to verify the post, accidentally my cursor hovered over the user card of the person that will render in the close dialog (as dupe target) and the expanded user card is looks weird.

[image]

This is a z-index issue. The expanded user card is rendering behind the close dialong and hence only a part is visible.

The z-index of expanded user card is `1002` and the z index of close dialog is `3000`.

#### Expanded user card

[image]

#### Close dialog

[image]